# Android - Is it possible to use a database transaction with ContentProvider / ContentResolver?

Tags: android, transactions, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver, android-database

The following code performs a database operation only if an NFC operation succeeds:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = ...;
db.beginTransaction();
try {
    // Update value in database
    String updatedValue = updateDatabaseValue(db);

    // Perform NFC operation with updatedValue
    performNfcOperation(updatedValue); // throws Exception

    // NFC operation succeeded, so commit the db update
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
}
finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}
```

How can I create the equivalent of this code using a `ContentResolver` instead of a `SQLiteDatabase`?

I have already created a `ContentProvider` for the database. I just don't know how/if it's possible to use transactions by accessing the database via a `ContentResolver`.

Comment: "I have already created a ContentProvider for the database" -- then the transaction needs to be inside the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: OK, so presumably the best approach would be to create a new URI for my content provider (e.g., `CONTENT_URI_UPDATE_WITH_NFC`), then detect the matching URI in my content provider's `update()` method to perform the transaction/NFC functionality?

Comment: The problem, though, is that my `performNfcOperation()` method needs to be called from an activity, so I don't see how I get reference the activity from my content provider's `update()` method(??).

Comment: I'm not sure of the scope of your new `Uri`. You should not need a new authority. Use a different path, akin to how you might do that with a REST-style Web service. If your objective is to have an exception from `performNfcOperation()` trigger a `ROLLBACK`, though, I have no idea how you would do that, short of getting rid of the `ContentProvider` and working with the database directly.

Comment: Yes, it's the rollback that is the essential part. I need the content provider for other parts of my app but, in this activity, it looks like I am stuck with working with the database directly and just calling `getContentResolver().notifyChange(CONTENT_URI_UPDATE, null)` after my call to `db.endTransaction()`